# In the context of Normal distribution, could $\mu$ and $\sigma$ be any value, such as $10^{-99}, 10^{-100}$, or even $\infty$, $-\infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

this is the PDF of a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

${\displaystyle f(x\mid \mu ,\sigma ^{2})={\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi \sigma ^{2}}}}e^{-{\frac {(x-\mu )^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}}}}$

where

- $\mu$  is the mean or expectation of the distribution (and also its median and mode)
- $\sigma$  is the standard deviation

Is there a notion like the domain of definition of a function to specify a range where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ take on.

In another word, could $\mu$ and $\sigma$ be any value, such as $10^{-99}, 10^{-100}$, or even $\infty$, $-\infty$?

Comment: $\mu$ can be any real number and $\sigma$ can be any positive real number.

Answer (score 1):

$\mu$ can be any real number and $\sigma$ can be any positive real number.  They cannot be $\pm \infty$ as those are not numbers and we cannot plug them into the formula.  There is nothing special about $\mu$ having a tiny value.  If $\sigma$ is tiny the value of the random variable is forced to be very close to the mean.

Comment: In the sense of distributions, $\sigma$ can be $0$. You get the degenerate distribution.

Comment: Yes but the OP is talking about it as a PDF over real numbers, so here $\sigma >0$. @eyeballfrog